# Sync Two ScrollView

Tags: android, android-widget

**Situation:**
I have two ScrollView inside of each of two HorizontalScrollView of a TableRow.

**Goal:**
When I touch drag one of ScrollView, another ScrollView must scroll as much. For instance, if I have a list of name on left ScrollView and corresponding phone numbers in right ScrollView, scrolling one ScrollView should not destroy the original bounding between the names and phone numbers.

Can it be implemented by onTouchEvent? If so, how should I implement this(on both or one of the ScrollView)?

Please help me out Android Gurus!

Comment: have you tried extending ScrollView to you can override the onTouchEvent method and use that to call onTouchEvent on your other scrollview and pass it the same event?

Answer (score 19):

I have a simple solution that works for me:

- subclass both `ScrollView`s and override their `onScrollChanged` event to update `ScrollManager` when scrolling changes:

  ```
  public interface ScrollNotifier {   
      public void setScrollListener(ScrollListener scrollListener);

      public ScrollListener getScrollListener();
  }

  public class SyncedScrollView extends ScrollView implements ScrollNotifier {

      //...

      private ScrollListener scrollListener = null;

      @Override
      protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
          super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
          if (scrollListener != null)
              scrollListener.onScrollChanged(this, l, t, oldl, oldt);
      }
      @Override
      public void setScrollListener(ScrollListener scrollListener) {
          this.scrollListener = scrollListener;
      }
      @Override
      public ScrollListener getScrollListener() {
          return scrollListener;
      }
  }
  ```
- create a `ScrollManager` class that coordinates the scrolling of multiple participants

  ```
  public interface ScrollListener {
      void onScrollChanged(View syncedScrollView, int l, int t, int oldl,
          int oldt);
  }

  public class ScrollManager implements ScrollListener {
      private static final int SCROLL_HORIZONTAL = 1;
      private static final int SCROLL_VERTICAL = 2;

      private ArrayList<ScrollNotifier> clients = new ArrayList<ScrollNotifier>(4);

      private volatile boolean isSyncing = false;
      private int scrollType = SCROLL_HORIZONTAL;

      public void addScrollClient(ScrollNotifier client) {
          clients.add(client);
          client.setScrollListener(this);
      }

      // TODO fix dependency on all views being of equal horizontal/ vertical
      // dimensions
      @Override
      public void onScrollChanged(View sender, int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
          // avoid notifications while scroll bars are being synchronized
          if (isSyncing) {
              return;
          }

          isSyncing = true;

          // remember scroll type
          if (l != oldl) {
              scrollType = SCROLL_HORIZONTAL;
          } else if (t != oldt) {
              scrollType = SCROLL_VERTICAL;
          } else {
              // not sure why this should happen
              isSyncing = false;
              return;
          }

          // update clients
          for (ScrollNotifier client : clients) {
              View view = (View) client;
              // don't update sender
              if (view == sender) {
                  continue;
              }

              // scroll relevant views only
              // TODO Add support for horizontal ListViews - currently weird things happen when ListView is being scrolled horizontally
              if ((scrollType == SCROLL_HORIZONTAL && view instanceof HorizontalScrollView)
                      || (scrollType == SCROLL_VERTICAL && view instanceof ScrollView)
                      || (scrollType == SCROLL_VERTICAL && view instanceof ListView)) {
                  view.scrollTo(l, t);
              }
          }

          isSyncing = false;
      }
  }
  ```
- create the custom `ScrollView`s and set the `ScrollManager` for notification on both

  ```
  private void setupScrolling() {
      ScrollNotifier view;
      ScrollManager scrollManager = new ScrollManager();

      // timeline horizontal scroller
      view = (ScrollNotifier) findViewById(R.id.epgtimeline_container);
      scrollManager.addScrollClient(view);

      // services vertical scroller
      view = (ScrollNotifier) findViewById(R.id.epgservices_container);
      scrollManager.addScrollClient(view);

      // content area scrollers
      view = (ScrollNotifier) findViewById(R.id.epgevents_container_inner);
      scrollManager.addScrollClient(view);
      view = (ScrollNotifier) findViewById(R.id.epgevents_container_outer);
      scrollManager.addScrollClient(view);
  }
  ```

Comment: Superb answer, was breaking my head on this for 2 days now trying to use the onTouchEvent and passing that trough. I finally got that working but it only worked one way.. this fixes all my issues... ;-) ... almost all my issues haha

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [andig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608395/andig) for such a great [synching scrollview solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5170022).

But there is little bit lag between both scrollviews while flinging.

So i am writing here extended solution to remove that lag between both scrollview.

I have just used OverScroller class and handled fling event manually in SyncedScrollView.

You have to just replace SyncedScrollView with below code.
Use other classes from [andig's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5170022)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.OverScroller;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

/**
 * Created by mitul.varmora on 11/7/2016.
 * SyncedScrollView
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527119/sync-two-scrollview
 */
public class SyncedScrollView extends ScrollView implements ScrollNotifier {

    private ScrollListener scrollListener = null;

    private OverScroller scroller;
    private Runnable scrollerTaskRunnable;

    public SyncedScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public SyncedScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public SyncedScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        scroller = new OverScroller(getContext());
        scrollerTaskRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scroller.computeScrollOffset();

                smoothScrollTo(0, scroller.getCurrY());

                if (!scroller.isFinished()) {
                    SyncedScrollView.this.post(this);
                } else {
                    //deceleration ends here, do your code
                    ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(SyncedScrollView.this);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if (scrollListener != null)
            scrollListener.onScrollChanged(this, l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }

    @Override
    public ScrollListener getScrollListener() {
        return scrollListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void setScrollListener(ScrollListener scrollListener) {
        this.scrollListener = scrollListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void fling(int velocityY) {

        scroller.forceFinished(true);
        scroller.fling(getScrollX(), getScrollY(), 0, velocityY, 0, 0, 0, getChildAt(0).getHeight());
        post(scrollerTaskRunnable);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
//        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        boolean eventConsumed = super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        if (eventConsumed && ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (scroller.isFinished()) {
                //do your code
            }
        }
        return eventConsumed;
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the onTouchEvent with this:
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean consumed = super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        if (consumed && ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            scroller.forceFinished(true);
        }
        return consumed;
    }

This perfectly fits my needs, thanks! :-)