# Synchronize Two HorizontalScrollViews Android

Tags: java, android, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I have two `HorizontalScrollView`s in my layout and I want to move them at the same. So if I touch scrollview a I want to move scrollview b at the same time and vice versa. I have done some searching around and haven't found a good solution. I have gotten it close by setting an `onTouchListener()` and trying to manually move each but I can't get it to move smoothly. Any ideas?

Comment: This is for ScrollView but you can modify https://stackoverflow.com/a/5170022/1882121

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out what I needed to do. I noticed that there is a protected method called `onScrollChanged()` in the `ScrollView` and `HorizontalScrollView` classes. So I subclassed `HorizontalScrollView` and implemented that method manually. From there I just created a callback that gets called when `onScrollChanged()` is invoked. Works like a charm. Why Google didn't make that method public is beyond me.

Comment: How do you manage the infinite loop issue, when the two handler calls each other? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38665677/how-to-synchronize-two-scrollview-in-android