# How to synchronize two scrollview in Android?

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview, android-scrollview, horizontal-scrolling

I have two horizontal `scrollview`, and want to keep them always at the same position / distance. If user scrolls one, need to scroll programmatically the other. The challenge is, that an infinite loop will occur. One will raise the other, other will raise first. How can I set a state, indicate that a user initiated scroll is still in progress? So other `scrollview` should not execute the programmatic scroll.

One of them is a `HorizontalScrollView` other is a `RecyclerView`.

Tried solutions like below, without any success:

```
horizontalScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {

            if (programmaticScrollEnable) {
                programmaticScrollEnable = false;
                // do programmatic scrolling here
                programmaticScrollEnable = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Tried to change state in `onScrollStateChanged` method:

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

    /*if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        MainActivity.programmaticScrollEnable = true;
    }*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
horizontalScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {

   recyclerView.scrollTo(horizontalScrollView.scrollTo(horizontalScrollView.getScrollX(), 0);

    }
});
```

Comment: any idea about this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58848391/how-do-i-synchronize-scrollview-positions-of-dynamic-horizontal-scroll-views-ins

Answer (score 0):

> The challenge is, that an infinite loop will occur.

You can avoid the infinite loop by registering the last touched `ScrolledView` in `OnTouchListener`. This touched `ScrollView` must not scroll programmatically; but the other(s) should be.

This can be tracked by setting a tag to each `ScrollView` and compare that tag during scroll event.

If you are API level 23 (Android M), you can register [`View.OnScrollChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnScrollChangeListener). And for APIs below that, you can register [`ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener). But the latter is heavy on the resources; so you need to handle that.

### For API levels 23+

```
// Tracking last touched SV
private var touchedSVTag = -1

// list of ScrollViews
val svs = arrayListOf(scrollview1, scrollview2)

val scrollListener =
    View.OnScrollChangeListener { view, scrollX, _, _, _ ->

        val currentSVTag = view!!.tag as Int

        if (currentSVTag == touchedSVTag) {
            for (svTag in 0 until svs.size) 
                if (svTag != currentSVTag) 
                    svs[svTag].scrollTo(scrollX, 0)
        }
    }

val itemTouchListener = View.OnTouchListener { sv, _ ->
    val svTag = sv.tag as Int

    if (touchedSVTag != -1 && touchedSVTag != svTag) {
        // stop scrollView in the middle of the scroll
        svs[touchedSVTag].fling(0)
    }

    touchedSVTag = svTag
    false
}

for (i in 0 until svs.size) {
    val sv = svs[i]
    sv.tag = i
    sv.setOnScrollChangeListener(scrollListener)
    sv.setOnTouchListener(itemTouchListener)
}
```

### And for API levels below 23:

```
// Tracking last touched SV
private var touchedSVTag = -1

// list of ScrollViews
val svs = arrayListOf(scrollview1, scrollview2)

val scrollListener = {
    val scrolledSV = svs[touchedSVTag]
    for (svTag in 0 until svs.size) 
        if (svTag != touchedSVTag)
            svs[svTag].scrollTo(scrolledSV.scrollX, 0)
}

val itemTouchListener = View.OnTouchListener { sv, _ ->
    val svTag = sv.tag as Int

    if (touchedSVTag != -1 && touchedSVTag != svTag) {
        // stop scrollView in the middle of the scroll
        svs[touchedSVTag].fling(0)
    }

    touchedSVTag = svTag
    false
}

for (i in 0 until svs.size) {
    val sv = svs[i]
    sv.tag = i
    sv.viewTreeObserver.addOnScrollChangedListener(scrollListener)
    sv.setOnTouchListener(itemTouchListener)
}
```