# Synchronize scrolling of two ScrollViews inside a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview, android-scrollview, synchronized-scrolling

I need to synchronize the scrolling positions of two `ScrollViews`.

Both `ScrollViews` contain their individual `RecyclerView` (I can't put them inside same ScrollView due to design requirements).

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Do the RecyclerViews contain the same data?

Comment: Why do you want to use a ScrollView at all? The RecyclerView has its own scroll logic! :)

Comment: no they contain different data.. @progressive_overload

Comment: So if one is scrolled to the end the other one may still have space to the bottom, because it contains more data? Do you want an abosolute mapping of the scrolling or a relative?

Comment: For syncing ScrollViews in their simplest form, [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38665677/how-to-synchronize-two-scrollview-in-android/71187343#71187343)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend that you CHANGE YOUR DESIGN but there is a way to achieve this

for first scroll view, define two variable x,y and get current scroll position

```
x = firstScrollView.getScrollX();
y = firstScrollView.getScrollY();
```

and pass these values to other scrollView "scrollTo" method.

like:

```
ScrollView secondScrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
secondScrollView.scrollTo(x, y);
```

if didn't work try:

```
secondScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
       secondScrollView.scrollTo(x, y);
              }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `NestedScrollView` from Support library since it enables us to listen scroll events easily. Then, set `onScrollChange` listeners for both `NestedScrollView` you have. When you receive scroll change for `scrollView1` for instance, call `scrollTo(...)` for `scrollView2`:

```
scrollView1.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

            scrollView2.setOnScrollChangeListener(null);
            scrollView2.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
            scrollView2.setOnScrollChangeListener(...); //SET SCROLL LISTENER AGAIN

        }
});
```

Before calling `scrollTo(..)` for `scrollView2`, remove its listener, then add it again. Otherwise, `scrollTo(..)` you call can cause infinite calls in both listeners of `NestedScrollView`s.

And of course, you need to write similar above code for your `scrollView2`.

Comment: no critique just an honest question: why using a ScrollView at all and then even a NestedScrollView? A RecyclerView has its own scroll logic by default (see my answer).

Comment: The question is about syncing ScrollViews. I don't care what s/he wants to put inside them.

Comment: i see, this way your answer would be more universal

Comment: I know that RecyclerView has its own scroll logic by default. But the app I am making demands such action. Actually the design is much complex....
I asked this question to solve a specific design problem which I'm facing.
@progressive_overload

Answer (score 0):

Attach an `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` to both [`RecyclerViews`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) via `addOnScrollListener(RecyclerView.OnScrollListener listener)`.

Update the position of the other one when the event is fired via: `scrollTo(int x, int y)`.

Remember to somehow distinguish between a user-triggered scroll and a programmtic scroll (from the other `RecyclerViews` event).

One way would be, like [Ugurcan Yildirim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5250273/ugurcan-yildirim) suggested, to detach the listener of the `ScrollView` you want to update.

Another option is a boolean flag `isUserTriggered`. A third way would be to determine which ScrollView currently has the focus to distinguish (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385081/how-can-i-change-the-edittext-text-without-triggering-the-text-watcher/33151589#33151589)).